# How to set TimeToLive Parameter in ActiveMQ via AJAX?

Tags: java, ajax, jakarta-ee, jms, activemq-classic

I have a question about **ActiveMQ** and the **AJAX** Interface concerning the life span of a message. In the AMQ web interface, I can set a **TimeToLive** Value for a message in milliseconds. 
I've already found out, that I can use this parameter via REST:

```
curl -vd  body="test" "http://localhost:8161/demo/message/TESTQUEUE?type=queue&JMSTimeToLive=500&JMSPersistent=-1"
```

This example message will live 500ms

But how can I use the AMQ Ajax Interface to set those parameters? 
The JavaScript function to send a message provides only two parameters

```
amq.sendMessage(myDestination,myMessage);
```

Info: http://activemq.apache.org/ajax.html

myDestination is unfortunately not an URL, it's something like this "queue://"

Thanks four your help

Regards
Rolf

Answer (score 0):

The current implementation of the AJAX client does not offer the possibility to send a message with a time to live.

The time to leave of the message is basically set in the [message property](http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-message-properties.html) (headers), via the property "JMSExpiration"
Currently if you go through the [amq.js code](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/activemq/trunk/activemq-web-demo/src/main/webapp/js/amq.js), you see there is no API that allows you to define the headers or Time to Live.

It should be relatively easy to add this feature to the client. [Check the code](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/activemq/trunk/activemq-web-demo/src/main/webapp/js/amq.js), you could probably just hardcode the TTL for your application. At the end, it just does a post command in the same way that you do your REST call.